# EF Core custom attributes not working for object types on modeBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I have a custom attribute class defined like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class JsonFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public JsonFieldAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

By using reflection to get this attribute usage on any class works perfect. Nothing fancy.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonField]
    public string Primitive { get; set; }

    [JsonField]
    public Address NonPrimitive { get; set; }
}
```

But by using modeBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes() on DbContexts's OnModelCreating only works with primitive types. It seems that any class type is ignored.

```cs
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var entityTypes in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            foreach (var property in entityTypes.GetProperties())
            {
                var memberInfo = property.PropertyInfo ?? (MemberInfo)property.FieldInfo;
                if (memberInfo == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(memberInfo, typeof(JsonFieldAttribute));
                // I've tried various combinations here, but all of them failed
                // var attr = memberInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<JsonFieldAttribute>();
                if (attr == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Custom attribute {property.Name} {attr.GetType().Name}");
            }
        }
  }
```

The output contains the following:

Custom attribute Primitive JsonFieldAttribute

I'm using .NET Core 2.1.403 and package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v 2.1.5. 
Any idea why NonPrimitive is not working?

Comment: is it that you did not include the non-primitive during select or define its forieng key properties? I think by default it wont lazy load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because collection and entity (owned or regular) types (in other words, navigation properties) by EF Core terminology are not properties, but *navigations*, and are not included in `GetProperties` method result, but instead can be retrieved with [GetNavigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.mutableentitytypeextensions.getnavigations?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_MutableEntityTypeExtensions_GetNavigations_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableEntityType_) method.

Since `IProperty` and `INavigation` share a common base `IPropertyBase`, you can combine them with `Concat` method and change your loop like this:

```
foreach (var property in entityTypes.GetProperties()
    .Concat<IPropertyBase>(entityType.GetNavigations()))
{
    // ...
}
```